# Calculating and indexing mcmc chains in coda

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, jags, rjags

There are two things I need to do. Firstly I would like to be able to create new variables in a `coda` mcmc object that have been calculated from existing variables so that I can run chain diagnostics on the new variable. Secondly I would like to be able to index single variables in some of the coda plot functions while still viewing all chains.

Toy data. Bayesian t-test on the sleep data using `JAGS` and `rjags`.

```
data(sleep)

# read in data
y <- sleep$extra
x <- as.numeric(as.factor(sleep$group))
nTotal <- length(y)
nGroup <- length(unique(x)) 
mY <- mean(y)
sdY <- sd(y)

# make dataList
dataList <- list(y = y, x = x, nTotal = nTotal, nGroup = nGroup, mY = mY, sdY = sdY)

# model string
modelString <- "
model{

    for (oIdx in 1:nTotal) {
    y[oIdx] ~ dnorm(mu[x[oIdx]], 1/sigma[x[oIdx]]^2)
    }

    for (gIdx in 1:nGroup) {
    mu[gIdx] ~ dnorm(mY, 1/sdY)
    sigma[gIdx] ~ dunif(sdY/10, sdY*10)
    }
}
" 
writeLines(modelString, con = "tempModel.txt")

# chains

  # 1. adapt
  jagsModel <- jags.model(file = "tempModel.txt",
                          data = dataList,
                          n.chains = 3,
                          n.adapt = 1000)

  # 2. burn-in
  update(jagsModel, n.iter = 1000)

  # 3. generate
  codaSamples <- coda.samples(model = jagsModel,
                              variable.names = c("mu", "sigma"),
                              thin = 15,
                              n.iter = 10000*15/3)
```

**Problem one**

If I convert the `coda` object to a dataframe I can calculate the difference between the estimates for the two groups and plot this new variable, like so...

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(codaSamples))
names(df) <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", names(df), perl = T) # remove brackets
df$diff <- df$mu1 - df$mu2
ggplot(df, aes(x = diff)) + 
       geom_histogram(bins = 100, fill = "skyblue") + 
       geom_vline(xintercept = mean(df$diff), colour = "red", size = 1, linetype = "dashed")
```

...but how do I get a traceplot? I can get one for existing variables within the coda object like so...

```
traceplot(codaSamples[[1]][,1])
```

...but I would like to be able to get them for the the new `diff` variable.

**Problem Two**

Which brings me to the second problem. I would like to be able to get a traceplot (among other things) for individual variables. As I have shown above I can get them for a single variable if I only want to see one chain but I'd like to see all chains. I can see all chains for all variables in the model with the simple

plot(codaSamples)

...but what if I don't want or need to see all variables? What if I just want to see the trace and/or desnity plots for one, or even two, variables (but not all variables) but with all chains in the plot?